# Answer seeking clarification was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I just saw that an answer I posted is deleted:

[Letter inside square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154819/letter-inside-square/27154868#27154868)

In my response I tried to express my opinion on one of the two alternative solutions

> Why are you not considering the option of putting each letter separately inside an inline element with border ?

Is it because I asked for clarification from the author? I have mentioned in my comment that I do not have enough reputation to comment on the question. If required I will be happy to edit / remove the clarification question, but I don't understand why a response upvoted by the author is deleted.

Answer (score 22):

You were told *exactly* what's wrong with this answer in the comment to your post:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

You stated that you posted the comment as an answer because you don't have enough reputation to post a comment.  **That doesn't make it okay to post a comment as an answer**.  Your post was deleted accordingly.

When you've earned enough reputation to post comments on other user's posts, you'll be able to provide such information through a comment.

Comment: Never post comments in answers. I cringe every time I see one of those.